# social sharing plugin in phonegap iOS not working well

Tags: cordova, ios7, sencha-touch, phonegap-plugins

I have an issue in phonegap app am using this [socialSharing](https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/841) plugin in Android it work perfectly in iOS the social popup not showing until I go to task switcher or( multi task bar) then it appear maybe this video will make it clear [dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/tix3yfx6adpwbza/20140811_132105.mp4)

Comment: Hello, did you solve this issue?

Comment: I was able to fix this by adding gap://ready to the default-src section of the Content Security Policy I got it at the internet don't remember who posted, but it fixed to me.

Comment: <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * gap://ready; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' *">

Answer (score 0):

Check the following links may be it can help you:

1. https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin
2. https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/X-Services-PhoneGap-Build-Plugins-Demo

Comment: I already using this plugin as I said up there but the problem is it showing off when I go to multi task bar